# Numpy: How is this code different from each other?

Tags: python, numpy

Let `r` be an array where each element is an column index (less than `N`, size of `r` is `M`) and `P` be a `M`x`N` array.

The following two snippets behave differently. Why?

1.

```
P[:, r] += 1
```

2.

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    P[i, r[i]] += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one selects an entire column for each element of `r`. The second just an element. You can directly compare the two cases like so:

```
>>> P = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
>>> r = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4,))
>>> r
array([1, 1, 2, 0])
>>> 
>>> P[:, r]
array([[ 1,  1,  2,  0],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  3],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  6],
       [10, 10, 11,  9]])
>>> P[np.arange(4), r]
array([1, 4, 8, 9])
```

As you can see the second produces essentially the diagonal of the first.

You may profit from having a look at section "Combining advanced and basic indexing" in the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

`P[:, r]` in the first snippet selects the entire first axis (`:` is like `0:-1` here) and `r`-th second axis.

`P[i, r[i]]` in the for loop selects only the `i`-th first axis and `r[i]`-th second axis, which is just a single element.

Once that's clear, it's no surprising the two give different results.